# Date Regular Expression Not Returning True

Tags: php, regex

For some reason this is always returning false... when entering "2014 12 12" into the form. It is this format to enter into a database.

```
$date = trim($_POST['date']);
```

in my library.php i have :

```
function validateDate($date) {
    if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{2,4}[\-[[:space:]]]{1}[0-9]{1,2}[\-[[:space:]]]{1}[0-9]{1,2}$/',$date)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;       
    }
}
```

and in my php i have :

```
if (validateDate($date)){
    $dateCSS = 'style="border-color: #98faad;"';
}
else {
    $dateCSS = 'style="border-color: red;"';
    $flag = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regexp:

```
^[0-9]{2,4}[\-[:space:]]{1}[0-9]{1,2}[\-[:space:]]{1}[0-9]{1,2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

A more reliable way to validate a date is to use the [`datetime` extension](http://php.net/datetime).

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y d m') {
    return \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date) !== false;
}
```

This way you do not have to resort to using regular expressions, and you will be able to actually validate dates correctly (for example, something like `2014 12 51` will not validate).

```
if ( ! validateDate('2014 12 51')) {
    echo 'Not valid!';
}
```

It will also allow you to validate more complicated dates, if you will be required to do that some day:

```
if (validateDate('16th September 2014', 'dS F Y')) {
    echo 'Valid!';
}
```

For the `$format` argument you must use the [formatting options](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-parameters) that `DateTime::createFromFormat()` accepts.